# REST API HTTP methods

Tags: rest, http

We are planning to use `GET` for all retrievals and `DELETE` for all delete operations. 
`HTTP PUT` , `POST` and `PATCH` is confusing. After a lot of reading, this is my understanding. Please correct if I am wrong.

`POST` - Not Idempotent ; so can be used for creating new resources/subordinate resource. Each time it creates a new one the ID gets changed and so it is best suited.

`PUT` - Idempotent; cannot be used for create since the second time the same request comes, it creates a new resource again with different ID. 
      Can be used for update but all attributes should be passed each time it is updated. To achieve this, a `GET` should be done prior to update operation. Overhead.

Why not use `POST` for updates too?

`PATCH` -Not sure if it is suitable for JAX-RS 1.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PUT` **may** be used for creation. With `PUT` you **provide the ID** (aka URI). Therefore, sending the same request another time **won't** create another resource but will update it (with the same content). That's why it is idempotent.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is this:

> Why not use POST for updates too?

The benefit of having `POST` and `PUT` make different types of changes to the resource you're allowing an extra vector of the request to modify the action without having to add more URLs. That way, URLs can stay short, clean, and reflective of what it is the represent.

However, to clear things up `PATCH` is often used for partial updates. So, like `PUT` it is idempotent, but will only modify the parts of the resource which you send in the request body whereas `PUT` is expected to modify the whole thing. This is often overlooked in REST. You can read more [on the Rest Cookbook website](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/).

Apart from that, from what I can tell your understanding is very good. Enjoy RESTing!